# How do I make a method which checks whether an event overlaps another event which a person is registered to?

Tags: java

I have a Class Tutor and a Class Event. The tutors can be enrolled from 0 to several events. Each event has a date, start time and end time. I would like to make a method which checks whether an event overlaps another event which means if a tutor is registered on an event starting 28/05/2018 at 14:00 and ending at 16:30  and he is also enrolled in an event at the same day starting at 13:00 and ending at 15:00, the events overlaps eachother and the method should then return true.

Here is my code so far:

```
public boolean overlap(Event event) {
    boolean overlap = false;

    // tutorList = arraylist of tutor objects
    for (Tutor t : tutorList) {
        for (Event e : t.getEvents()) {
            if (e.getDate().equals(event.getDate())) {
                if (e.getStartTime().isAfter(event.getStartTime())
                        && e.getStartTime().isBefore(event.getEndTime())) {
                    overlap = true;

                } else if (e.getEndTime().isAfter(event.getStartTime())
                        && e.getEndTime().isBefore(event.getEndTime())) {
                    overlap = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return overlap;
}
```

The problem with the method i have written is that it does not always return true as expected.

Comment: use a Debugger to find out what is happening

Comment: What are the types returned by `.getDate()`, `.getStartTime()`, and `.getEndTime()`?

Comment: "The problem with the method i have written is that it does not always return true as expected." - when does this happen? You should know or find out, and when you know that, you should get an idea what to fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution is not complete because you are only checking cases where there is a partial overlap, but you are not accounting for cases where one event starts and ends while another event is in progress.
Example:
Event A: 14:00 - 17:00
Event B: 15:00 - 16:00

You need to make sure your code returns true in that case as well.

One solution is to add the following two checks as well:

```
            if (event.getStartTime().isAfter(e.getStartTime())
                    && event.getStartTime().isBefore(e.getEndTime())) {
                overlap = true;

            } else if (event.getEndTime().isAfter(e.getStartTime())
                    && event.getEndTime().isBefore(e.getEndTime())) {
                overlap = true;
            }
```

Try to think of other edge cases. For example, what will happen when the two events have the exact start and end times?

Answer (score 1):

Use generic method and check both sides:

```
 public static boolean isOverlap(Event e, Event event) {
     return (e.getStartTime().isAfter(event.getStartTime())
                    && e.getStartTime().isBefore(event.getEndTime()));
```

Call twice

```
  overlap = isOverlap(e, event) || isOverlap(event, e)
```

Better option is to send first parameter the start date but you didn't disclose relevant object

Answer (score 0):

The problem of overlapping times can be solved graphically like this:

```
A |------------|
B           |-----------|
```

and

```
A         |------------|
B |-----------|
```

and

```
A    |-----|
B |-----------|
```

and

```
A |------------|
B   |------|
```

If you create the intervals with your fingers and slide them from side to side you should be able to realize that for the interval to overlap:

```
A.start is before B.end
&&
B.start is before A.end
```

Nothing more, nothing less.

Also, you should break when you know the result:

```
public boolean overlap(Event event) {

    // tutorList = arraylist of tutor objects
    for (Tutor t : tutorList) {
       for (Event e : t.getEvents()) {
            if (e.getDate().equals(event.getDate())) {
                if (e.getStartTime().isBefore(event.getEndTime())
                        && event.getStartTime().isBefore(e.getEndTime())) {
                    return true;
                } 
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```